# Spacing Words Equally Across Line in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

There are several words in one line—for example, pineapple, orange, and grape. I want to locate these three with two identical spaces using one complete line in Word. If I use tabbing at 3.25 in and 6.5 in respectively, then the first and second spaces will not match as pineapple is longer than grape as follows.

```
+-------------++-------------+
pineapple   orange       grape
+-------------++-------------+
```

rather than

```
+-------------++-------------+
pineapple     orange     grape
+-------------++-------------+
```

I consider neither a distributed alignment nor a table as they do not coordinate well with other sentences. How can I achieve the equal spacing in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you can use a fixed-width font, use spaces instead of tabs and ensure there are the same number of spaces on each side.
2. If not, you could type

   ```
   pineapple<tab>pineappleorangegrape<tab>grape
   ```

   (in other words, duplicate the word "pineapple", however it is formatted, and duplicate the word "orange", however it is formatted)

   Then change the colour of the middle "pineapple" and "orange" texts to white. I tried that here and although Word never quite balances the space on either side, it seems close.
3. Otherwise, I think you would probably need to VBA that measured the text widths of "pineapple" and "grape", e.g. looking at the values of

   ```
   Range.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary)
   ```

   at the beginning and end of each word. Then either set the middle tab at the appropriate distance or measure the width of a single space calculate how many you can fit in on either side of the middle text, and insert them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use a 3 column table, and apply equal width to each column with text centrally aligned? That in my experience works without fuss.

Comment: To further add to the illusion, setting the borders to clear/no-fill makes it invisible and looks almost the same as no table at all.

Comment: Thanks, but this approach creates two unequal spaces as a result.